# UWP ObservableCollection with data from webservice not updating GUI

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, observablecollection, windows-10-universal

I'm using an ObservableCollection on a listview. The ObservableCollection get its data correctly from a web service using an async method then parses it and fill the ObservableCollection with the Add method on the NewsProxyParser(string thing, out ObservableCollection newsList) method, but i'm not able to update the GUI with the binded ObservableCollection.

I'm new to UWP, so i suppose that the async method runs on a different thread that the GUI. How can i do correctly the bind to update the GUI with the data fetched from the web service?

My XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView Name="ListViewNews" ItemsSource="{x:Bind NewsCollection, Mode=OneWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:News">

                <RelativePanel Margin="0,16" >
                    <Image Name="x:Thumb" Source="{x:Bind thumbnailUrl}" Width="96" Height="96" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Margin="0,0,16,0"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Name="x:Title" Text="{x:Bind title}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold"  RelativePanel.RightOf="x:Thumb"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="x:Date" Text="{x:Bind dateString}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="Gray" RelativePanel.RightOf="x:Thumb" RelativePanel.Below="x:Title"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="x:Text" Text="{x:Bind newsText}" Foreground="Gray"  RelativePanel.RightOf="x:Thumb" RelativePanel.Below="x:Date"></TextBlock>
                </RelativePanel>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>                       
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And the cs:

```
public sealed partial class NewsPage : Page
{

    private ObservableCollection<News> NewsCollection;

    public NewsPage()
    {
        NewsRequest();
        this.InitializeComponent();                     
    }

    private async void NewsRequest()
    {
        //Fetch News from web
        string response =  await NewsProxy.GetNews("TokenX");
        //Parse News to add to NewsCollection
        bool success = NewsProxy.NewsProxyParser(response, out NewsCollection);

        // success is true and NewsCollection has new updated values

        if (success)
        {
            News n = new News();
            n.title = "Just to trigger collectionchanged";
            n.newsText = "dadada";
            n.order = 1;
            NewsCollection.Add(n);
            Debug.WriteLine("Still No GUI updated!!!");

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<>` only notifies of collection changes, such as adding and removing items. As long as you replace the whole collection, you will need to make `NewsCollection` a dependency property to notify XAML UI about the changes.

```
public ObservableCollection<News> NewsCollection
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<News>)GetValue(NewsCollectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NewsCollectionProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NewsCollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("NewsCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<News>), typeof(NewsPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

private async void NewsRequest()
{
    //Fetch News from web
    string response =  await NewsProxy.GetNews("TokenX");
    //Parse News to add to NewsCollection
    ObservableCollection<News> newsCollection;
    bool success = NewsProxy.NewsProxyParser(response, out newsCollection);
    NewsCollection = newsCollection;

    // success is true and NewsCollection has new updated values

    if (success)
    {
        News n = new News();
        n.title = "Just to trigger collectionchanged";
        n.newsText = "dadada";
        n.order = 1;
        NewsCollection.Add(n);
        Debug.WriteLine("Still No GUI updated!!!");
    }
}
```